# OpenLayers Interaction - events are returning wrong features

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-layer

Trying to extract the drawn features on openlayers. I have written the below code and it is working fine when we draw polygon on four objects. But, when we try to draw polygon on three objects it is returning four features instead of three, not sure why the function(evt.feature.getGeometry().getExtent()) is returning four features when polygon drawn on three objects on a map.

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: sourceMeasure,
        type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon')
    });
    openlayerMap.addInteraction(draw);

    draw.on('drawstart',
            function(evt) {
        // set sketch
    }, this);

    draw.on('drawend',
            function(evt) {

        var extent = evt.feature.getGeometry().getExtent();

        vectorSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {

            var layer = feature.get('LAYER');
            /* here my logic is written and it working fine with four coordinates */

        });

    }, this);
```

Comment: seems like working fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrvWbW

Comment: No. It's not working. It is working only with a square box selection but for polygon it's not working. Is there any workaround?

Comment: or could you make a fiddle to show the wrong behavior?

Comment: Chase Choi, I used the same fiddle the one you provided. I have drawn four   small squares on the map in two columns, and drawn the polygon intersecting only 3 squares. But it is returning four features instead of three.

Comment: the coordinate of extent is always rectangle that's why you get wrong number of features. though you draw polygon, its extent is the maximum boundary rectangle. as you see http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.Extent

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Could you please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: There's no easy way with API itself. You can ask OpenLayers team or do math things with coordinates.

Comment: Chase, is there a way to add some identifier when ever click we clicked inside a polygon?. So that I can check the same in 'draw end' function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party library like [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) to solve your issue.

You can find out how to select exactly by polygon instead of extend by looking at [this sample](https://rawgit.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-extras-demos/master/select-jsts/select-advanced.html)